# Custom Text in Views

Tags: views

In drupal 7, I created block in views and add field **Global: Custom text**, and write some text in this field.

When display this block and inspect show **Global: Custom text** in **span** tag.

How to display **Global: Custom text** but not in **span** tag.

Comment: Did you unchecked the checkbox "Create a label" in the settings for this field?

Comment: Did you checked the "Exclude from dispaly" option..?

Comment: Create a label checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Abin, i want to display field, but not span tag.

Comment: It will create a wrapper `element`, unless you modify the `field tempalte`

Answer (score 2):

You can turn them off in "**Global: Custom Text**" field setting. Just check the "**Customize field HTML**" and "**Customize field and label wrapper HTML**", and set both elements to "**None**" in "**Style Settings**". See below screenshot for details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can choose **Global Php** variable from listing when add different varible of content type from listed variables in view.